# EF Caching Provider Wrapper is not working with EF 6.0.2

Tags: c#, caching, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6 with 2nd level caching with EF Provider Wrappers but it is not working.

I am getting this error:

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'EFCachingProvider'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

After looking on the above link, I used config file registration after that the following error occurs:

> The 'Instance' member of the Entity Framework provider type 'EFCachingProvider.EFCachingProviderFactory, EFCachingProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=def642f226e0e59b' did not return an object that inherits from 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices'. Entity Framework providers must inherit from this class and the 'Instance' member must return the singleton instance of the provider. This may be because the provider does not support Entity Framework 6 or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to changes to the provider model in EF6 (and some other features) the EF Caching Provider does not work with EF6+ versions. I created a Second Level Cache for EF 6.1 - see [this blog post](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/03/20/second-level-cache-for-ef-6-1/) for more details.

Comment: @Pawel The project I'm currently working the initial developers chose to go model first rather than code first :(. I'm trying to get 2nd level caching working with EF6.1 using the DbContext, and I'm assuming your solution doesn't work with model first? I've had a look at implementing a class implementing the IDbCommandInterceptor, but it's proving to be a little tough as I'm wanting certain entities cached indefinitely, while others not. Do you perhaps know how I'm able to accomplish this?

Comment: I have not tried but I think it actually should work fine for ModelFirst too. In EF6 model first uses DbContext too and I think the configuration will apply because the main difference between CodeFirst and non-CodeFirst approaches is that the latter uses edmx while the former builds edmx (or to be more accurate MSL and in memory representations of CSDL and SSDL) from the code.